# Error after updating from ASP MVC 3 Beta to RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

After I updated my ASP MVC 3 application from the beta version to the realease candidate I encounter this error:

```
{"Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection.Add(System.Object, System.Nullable`1<Int32>)'."}
```

The error occurs in `Global.asax` inside this code:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); // <-- Here
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Here is my `RegisterGlobalFilters()`

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

Here is the details of my System.Web.MVC.dll:
[image]

The System.Web.MVC.dll file is actually missing from the assembly folder, should it be here?
[image]

Here is a screenshot of all MVC applications installed on my computer, the beta was unsintalled before I did a new install of RC, I also installed through Microsoft Web Platform Installer so I think it should be ok:
[image]

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the RC version of System.Web.Mvc.dll in Reflector, I see a `private void AddInternal(object filter, int? order)` method.  It sounds like this used to be named `Add` in the beta.

The RC version is `3.0.11029.0`.  Check the version of the dll you have in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies`, and if you are seeing the error on a published/deployed web site, check the dll version there as well.

*Edit*

Found an installation note on the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034210):

> you must uninstall ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview 1 or ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta before installing ASP.NET MVC 3 RC.

I'm not sure what gets cleaned up by uninstalling the beta, but if you did not unininstall the beta, you might want to uninstall the RC and the beta, then reinstall the RC.

Comment: The version in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies` is the same as yours, `3.0.11029.0`.

Comment: @Martin, Do you get the same error on a new MVC 3 application?  Also, have you tried to do a clean and rebuild?

Comment: @Martin - did you uninstall the Beta before installing the RC?

Comment: Yes, it is working on a new MVC 3 application, and I did unsinstall all older MVC's. But i'll double check to see if I have missed something. I have updated my question with a screenshot of all MVC applications installed on my computer.

Comment: @Martin, well, I am out of ideas :(  Hopefully @Mariusz or someone else will have the answer.  I guess as a last resort, you could create a new MVC 3 project and copy your code over.

Comment: Thank you for ur effort anyways, I'll try to uninstall all MVC applications and do a fresh install, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method looks like in the default template of an ASP.NET MVC 3 RC application:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Does yours look the same? Obviously the second parameter (a `Nullable<int>`) has been removed from the `Add` method.

Comment: I have updated my code with my `RegisterGlobalFilters()` it looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the right version of System.Web.Mvc.dll on your test machine. Ff MVC 3 Beta is installed into the GAC then it will always win, even if you have the RC version in your app's bin folder. Try to find out from which directory your dll is being loaded.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of the System.Web.MVC.dll properties. Think it is correct, but i'll check the assembly aswell.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of my assembly folder aswell, looks like the dll is missing from the assembly.

Comment: What version do you have in c:\windows\assembly\gac?

Comment: Hmm.. I dont have a folder named gac inside assembly.. Am I minning something?

Comment: Sorry, gac is not needed. Can you check which version of yourSystem.Web.MVC.dll is registered in GAC? Try it with gacutil.exe /i <assemblyName>

Comment: I cant find gacutil.exe on my computer, I have looked in all the folders listed here: http://blogs.iis.net/davcox/archive/2009/07/14/where-is-gacutil-exe.aspx. Im using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.